# Using OR operator within Angular ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

having problems with the results. I have 2 variables: close and close1 - each assigned to it's own div. on click, a div will open only if the other is closed, and visa versa. i'm trying to use the OR operator to change the class using this condition:

Starts:
close = true;
close1 = false;

```
<div ng-click="close = !close" ng-class="{'close-div': close || !close1, 'open-div': !close}">
<div ng-click="close1 = !close1" ng-class="{'close-div': !close || close1, 'open-div': !close1}">
```

Unfortunately, still able to open both at the same time and I need the results to be one-at-a-time. Tried using the && operator as well and the results are the same. Be much appreciative for anyone's help. Thanks!

Comment: Should the second `open-div` class be `!close1` ?

Comment: Yes, it should and actually it is - a typo on my part :) This happens when one is working at 2am in the morning. I went ahead and edited the code - thank you for finding the typo. Wish it was the fix - but the problem is still there ...

Comment: This is a very good moment to start using unit tests. I suggest putting this logic in a scope publoshed function and circling it with tests. Shout if you need help :-)

Comment: Hi Loremlpsum - Thank you. I do need to learn the testing part - what are you're recommended tools to use for a newbie tester?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uslperera/pz58m91h/22/)

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div ng-click="close1=false; close = !close && !close1" ng-class="{'close-div': !close, 'open-div': close && !close1}">A</div>
<div ng-click="close=false; close1 = !close1 && !close" ng-class="{'close-div': !close1, 'open-div': close1 && !close}">B</div>
        {{close + ' ' + close1}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Shamal - Thank you for your demo, but it still isn't working the way I need it to and that is when one clicks to open, the other should automatically close and visa versa.

Comment: Hi @Jules2U I updated my answer check this http://jsfiddle.net/uslperera/pz58m91h/22/